# jQuery scrollTo limit to children

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm playing around with jQuery scrollTo, trying to make a smooth scrolling site with full body sections. The scroll and transitions are working fine, except when you scroll up from the first section, the script highlights the navigation panel as a section, instead of staying on section 1.

The example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8jh3qt5c/2/

Here's how the nav looks like:

```
<div id="header">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the scroll.js:

```
var $current, flag = false;

$(function() { 
$('#nav').onePageNav();

$('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    if (flag) { return false; }
    $current = $('div.current');

    if (delta > 0) {
        $prev = $current.prev();

        if ($prev.length) {
            flag = true;
            $('body').scrollTo($prev, 500, {
                onAfter : function(){
                    flag = false;
                }
            });
            $current.removeClass('current');
            $prev.addClass('current');
        }
    } else {
        $next = $current.next();

        if ($next.length) {
            flag = true;
            $('body').scrollTo($next, 500, {
                onAfter : function(){
                    flag = false;
                }
            });
            $current.removeClass('current');
            $next.addClass('current');
        }
    }

    event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

I can't seem to find a way to exclude the nav panel from the scroll, so when on the first panel, scrolling up won't have any effect.

Also, when you refresh the page on a lower section, is there a way to reset the current visible section to the first, as right now the window stays on whichever was current.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking whether the prev and next are still valid elements.
Here's a better approach, haven't tested adjust if there's any small issue.

```
$(function() { 
  $('#nav').onePageNav();

  $('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $current = $('div.current');
    if ($current.is(':animating')) return;

    var $next = delta > 0 ? $current.prev() : current.next();
    if (!$next.hasClass('section')) return;

    $current.removeClass('current');
    $next.addClass('current');
    $(window).scrollTo($next, 500);
  });
});
```

BTW, if you are using scrollTo, it's kind of a waste to use onePageNav. You can do the same by including [localScroll](https://github.com/flesler/localScroll) which uses scrollTo and doesn't reimplement the whole thing.

Alternatively, you can implement it shortly like this:

```
// Bind to the click of all links with a #hash in the href
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(window).stop(true).scrollTo(this.hash, {duration:500, interrupt:true});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ariel, but the code you provided does not work. I looked over to localScroll, but I could not find any information on using the mouse to scroll through with a nice animation (it only animates on click).

Comment: I said it could replace onePageNav not the whole thing. The mousewheel part needs to be done separatedly.

Comment: I fixed an error on my code, you can re-test it now. Replicating your case to test the code actually takes a long time, if you were to make a jsfiddle or similar It's way faster to try a different script

Comment: By the way, the HTML you provided up there is not the same as the one in the site, the site has a #header element before the sections